# How to open .tif in color (not black and white)

Tags: layers, images

I have scanned book.
Each page of the book consists of two files: one **.tif** file and one **.frf** file. (By the way, are they somehow compatible?)

If I open **.tif file** in viewer like Irfanview, GIMP, Paint or Advanced TIFF Editor Plus - it's displaying as black & white picture. In some editors I see this file has three layers and I think one layer contains information about colors.

My goal is to open this **.tif file** in color. Any ideas how to open it & merge layers? Or am I totally wrong in my assumptions? :)

[image]

Comment: If a tif file is color, then it generally opens in color. It may be due to that "trial version" designation in your screenshot.  It's pretty impossible to answer this specifically without having one of these .tif files to check.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably too late to answer to you Peter, but just in case it could be useful for somebody. I have the same problem - .tif & .frf files, that I can open only in black & white.
Long story short - in my case it was a set of file from the old version of ABBYY  FineReader OCR software. The files can be

Comment: Did you forget to finish this answer?